# Where is the value recorded with System.setProperty stored?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

In the following example `System.setProperty` used

```
public class LoadLogPropertiesFile {

    static {
        // must set before the Logger
        String path = LoadLogPropertiesFile.class.getClassLoader().getResource("logging.properties").getFile();
        System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", path);

    }

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoadLogPropertiesFile.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
```

As you might guess this will set the system property with the key `java.util.logging.config.file`, right?

From the docs

> This may result in a SecurityException being thrown. If no exception
> is thrown, the specified property is set to the given value.

As a result no exception was thrown and no system property with a given name was detected after this code finished. What is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "no system property with a given name was detected after this code finished"? `System.getProperty` should get you the value back. Where and how was it (not) detected? A process cannot modify the environment variables of a different process, as that would be a HUGE security problem.

Comment: @knittl I assumed that this would set a system variable, which can be found in the environment variables on Windows. If this is not the case, then where is this variable actually written?

Comment: A resource is **not** a file path (or, not necessarily). Also, I'm not 100% sure, but I think that `logger` will be initialized *before* that static initializer is run, so in that case the property will have already been tried with the initial (absent) value and is then ignored. If you want to avoid that, initialize the logger in the static block as well.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Note that I'm not asking anything for resource, but for system property...

Comment: `System.setProperty` will set the JVM property in the current JVM. JVM properties != OS environment variable.

Comment: Quite a bit of confusion here. [Better to state the *GOAL*](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/15-smart-questions)

Comment: You're resolving the value to assign as a resource, which doesn't necessarily have a filesystem representation, because it doesn't need to exist on the filesystem, existence on the classpath (e.g. in a JAR) is sufficient for resources, but not for `java.util.logging.config.file`.

Comment: Anyway, it is entirely possible that Java internals already initialized logging at that point (even with my suggestion to move the creation of the logger into the static initalizer(!)), which is why the `LogManager` documentation says _"These two properties may be specified on the command line to the "java" command, or as system property definitions passed to JNI_CreateJavaVM."_. Note how it doesn't say that it is possible to set it using `System.setProperty` in an already running Java process, probably because they cannot guarantee this too work.

Comment: In any case, add `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.util.logging.config.file"))` in the initializer or your `main` method, and you will see the property has been set to something.

Comment: afaik, unlike other logging frameworks, the logging configuration *must* be read from a file (without fundamental interference). That alone would rule out its use for me

Comment: @knittl in the description of this method did not contain the necessary information that would confirm or dispel my assumptions about the essence of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values that you set with `System.setProperty()` are stored in a `Properties` object of the currently running JVM. You can retrieve that `Properties` object through `System.getProperties()` or access values from that `Properties` object with `System.getProperty()`.

These properties are not made visible to any process outside of the currently running JVM.